# Testing contracts that have construction parameters

Tags: contract-development, truffle, testing

How do I test a contract with that has construction parameters? For example what if I had slightly modified the [metacoin example contract](https://github.com/ConsenSys/truffle-webpack-demo/blob/master/contracts/MetaCoin.sol) to include an `initial_balance`

```
contract MetaCoin {
  mapping (address => uint) balances;

  function MetaCoin(uint initial_balance) {
    balances[tx.origin] = initial_balance;
  }
  ...
```

How do I modify the example TestMetacoin.sol

```
import "truffle/Assert.sol";
import "truffle/DeployedAddresses.sol";
import "../contracts/MetaCoin.sol";

contract TestMetacoin {
  function testInitialBalanceUsingDeployedContract() {
    MetaCoin meta = MetaCoin(DeployedAddresses.MetaCoin());

    uint expected = 10000;

    Assert.equal(meta.getBalance(tx.origin), expected, "Owner should have 10000 MetaCoin initially");
  }
  ...
```

AFAIK the `truffle test` runner deploys the contracts and the `Metacoin(DeployedAddresses.Metacoin())` gets the deployed contract to test.  But I don't see any way to pass in the `initial_balance` to test it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two solutions.

**First solution**: change your migrations file and add second parameter here:

```
deployer.deploy(Contract, initial_balance)
```

---

**Second solution**: just deploy new contract inside your test:

```
contract TestMetacoin {
  function testInitialBalanceUsingDeployedContract() {
    MetaCoin meta = new MetaCoin(10000);

    uint expected = 10000;

    Assert.equal(meta.getBalance(tx.origin), expected, "Owner should have 10000 MetaCoin initially");
}
```

Comment: Ahh!  That makes a lot of sense.  I didn't realize that the truffle test runner uses the migrations to deploy the contracts.